# How can we interchange the display of tax in magento 2

Tags: magento2

At the product detail page, we need to interchange the position of 'Excl. Tax' and 'Incl. Tax'. 
Please check the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeeded to inverse the price value as per your screenshot.

you need to add a layout file called catalog_product_prices.xml with the content below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Mbs_ProductList::product/price/amount/inversetax.phtml</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

and then the template in the snippet above will be: (the path of the template can be changed of course but will need to matching in both layout above and its final physical location)

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAdjustmentCssClasses()) ?>"
        <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()) :?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getDisplayLabel()) ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()) :?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()) :?> id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceId()) ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes()) . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getDisplayValue()) ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceType()) ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getPriceWrapperCss()) ?>"
    ><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()), ['span']) ?> </span>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()) :?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getDisplayValue()) ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getDisplayCurrencyCode()) ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

In this answer, you have only the inversion. The suffixes inc. VAT and ex. VAT are not. To add these, I suspect the easiest is to use css (that is if you don't rely on internationalisation)